# How to work with sales force desktop

Tags: salesforce

I'm quit new to the SalesForce.I was handed over a tasking of getting all the details of "All Cases" in salesforce.But I have no idea regarding where to start.So I thought that someone could give me a push with an "API".I would like to have an API for .Net.As I'm working with it.

Comment: You can use the dataloader to extract all cases information.

Comment: Can u provide any sample code or article regarding this.